# How to print numbers as floats with a specified format in lisp?

Tags: format, common-lisp, coerce

An arbitrary number can be readily converted to float with some number of decimals. For example, using `(format nil "~,2f" 6)` gives `"6.00"`. But is there a way to directly coerce an arbitrary number using an analogous float type spec; i.e., outputting a number, not a string? Alternately, I've tried `(read-from-string (format nil "~,2f" 6))`, but this does not retain the formatting.

I would like to print a nested tree containing numbers (along with other lisp objects), as floats with two decimal places. For example,  a printout might look like `X -> (A 3.00 (7.10 B) (C 8.12) 0.75)` regardless of the specific number types represented in X. Is set-pprint-dispatch used for this kind of output or is format sufficient?

Comment: I think you are confusing a number with its printed representation.

Comment: Do you mean you want to coerce an integer into a float? As in `(float 6)`=> `6.0`? What do you mean with "retain the formatting"? Numbers in memory don't contain any formatting. You can format any number the way you want when you print them.

Comment: @sds Yes, now I see you are right. What I'm really trying to do is printout a number without the quotes. I should just use (format t "~,2f" 6) instead of (format nil "~,2f" 6). Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @davypough, I suggest editing your question to explicitly show that you were expecting `6.00`, but you were getting `"6.00"` - and then, if you feel comfortable that you now understand that `(format t...` was _printing_ `6.00`, while `(format nil ...` was _returning a string_ `"6.00"`, go ahead and write up an answer and accept it for the benefit of future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is set-pprint-dispatch used for this kind of output or is format sufficient?

Let's try with [`SET-PPRINT-DISPATCH`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set_pp.htm#set-pprint-dispatch):

```
CL-USER> (let ((*print-pprint-dispatch* (copy-pprint-dispatch)))
           (set-pprint-dispatch 'float (lambda (s f) (format s "~,2f" f)))
           (write '(A 3.00 (7.10 B) (C 8.12) 0.75) :pretty t))

(A 3.00 (7.10 B) (C 8.12) 0.75)  ;; standard output
(A 3.0 (7.1 B) (C 8.12) 0.75)    ;; result printed by the REPL
```

Since the pretty-print dispatch table is copied before being modified, the function associated with floats is only called from inside the let-binding. When the return value of [`WRITE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) is printed to the REPL, the default dispatch table is used. You could define a global variable to avoid recomputing the modified table each time you need it.

Note that if you don't give a value for `:pretty`, then the special [`*PRINT-PRETTY*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_pre.htm) variable defines whether the pretty-printer is used or not. For details see [22.2.1.4 Pretty Print Dispatch Tables](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_bad.htm).

> I would like to print a nested tree containing numbers

If what you want is to output *any number* as a float, just dispatch on the [`REAL`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_real.htm#real) type (complex numbers with non-zero imaginary parts can't be printed as you want, so I don't recommend dispatching on `number`). Any necessary coercion will happen implicitly:

```
(let ((*print-pprint-dispatch* (copy-pprint-dispatch)))
  (set-pprint-dispatch 'real (lambda (s f) (format s "~,2f" f)))
  (write '(A 3 (7.1d0 B) (C 203/25) #C(3/4 0)) :pretty t))
```

... writes:

```
(A 3.00 (7.10 B) (C 8.12) 0.75)
```

Comment: The application for this is a summary printout, so it works great. I've added `in-package` statements before & after `write` to suppress printing the package prefix for non-reals; and embedded the `write` statement in a loop to print each item in the top-level of the input tree on a separate line. (Please comment further if these are moot changes. Thank you for helping to organize my thinking about this.)

Comment: You're welcome, thank you. You can locally bind `*package*` instead of using `in-package`, which is simpler because you don't have to revert to the previous package explicitly, which could be error-prone. But I'd rather  set  `:escape` to NIL in the call to write to avoid printing packages. See http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_esc.htm#STprint-escapeST. You could also define custom pretty printer functions for symbols, like for numbers.

Answer (score 2):

To coerce numbers to float numbers use `coerce` or `float`:

```
CL-USER 121 > (float 2/3 1.0s0)
0.6666667

CL-USER 122 > (float 2/3 1.0d0)
0.6666666666666666D0

CL-USER 123 > (coerce 2/3 'double-float)
0.6666666666666666D0
```

Note that floats have limited precision - as usual.